# android.widget.CalendarView class cannot be instantiated

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I'm tyring to develop android apps on my mac.  With the following specs

```
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.6.0_33
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring 
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product
```

Basically when I drag a calendarview into my xml layout I get this error in the xml editor:

The following classes could not be instantiated:
-android.widget.CalendarView(Open Class, Show Error Log)

Below is the error log:

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2012-08-03 19:28:43.196
!MESSAGE android.widget.DatePicker failed to instantiate.
!STACK 0

    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.widget.CalendarView
        at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:212)
        at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:145)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:402)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:166)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:321)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:331)
        at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1640)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1391)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.reloadLayoutSwt(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1868)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.access$0(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1806)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener$1.run(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1800)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3944)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3621)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

PLEASE HELP

**EDIT**: This seems to only happen with SDK version 16.  SDK 15 opens and uses calendar views fine O.o

Comment: Make sure that you are on the latest version of the Android SDK tools and the ADT plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: tried that! And it didnt work... :(

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, please help.